# Can we have a setting that defaults our searches to Google?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, user-interface

I mean, Jeff has already stated he isn't trying to compete with Google. So why have a local site search anyway? Changing the form action value (or letting me choose between SO's and Google's) wouldn't be a drastic change and it would save me from having to open up a new tab, type what I'm looking for and append `site:stackoverflow.com` to the end.

Pretty please?

Comment: can't you just search with google?

Comment: why make me go to google's site to search SO, and why require me to have a google toolbar?  a google text box should replace the internal search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search page at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search has one-click search boxes for three major search engines.

(to get there, type in /search in the address bar, or just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search box at the upper right of every page)

http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/2957/searchoptions.png

Comment: Not anymore, this answer is obsolete. Really obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Google cannot offer StackOverflow-specific search features such as tag-specific searches:

- **[tag] apples oranges**
- **[tag] [another-tag] apples oranges**

... and other *Advanced Super Ninja Search Options*:

- **posts from a specific user** 
  [image: -] `user:1234 apples oranges`
- **posts with a minimum number of votes** 
   [image: -] `votes:15 apples
  oranges`
- **questions with a minimum number of views** 
   [image: -] `views:250 apples
  oranges`
- **questions that have an accepted answer** 
   [image: -] `hasaccepted:1 apples
  oranges`
- **answers that are accepted answers** 
   [image: -] `isaccepted:1 apples
  oranges`
- **questions that have a minimum number of answers** 
   [image: -] `answers:1
  apples oranges`
- **questions that have been closed** 
   [image: -] `closed:1 apples oranges`
- **posts that are community wiki** 
   [image: -] `wiki:1 apples oranges`

See full list on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search or just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search box at the upper right of every page.

Comment: this is not completely true.. tags show up as regular text in Google and so do usernames.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest that you take a look at setting up a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) and then you can base you searches on as many (or as little) sites as you want at a single time. Then you could even make that search engine your default search method.

Answer (score 1):

NO, please don't become one of those sites that uses Google Search, we can do better.  I always hate searching on those sites.  Google doesn't scale down well.

Comment: You won't even support me in letting the users choose? :(

Comment: No, that's why I didn't downvote you, choice is great.