# Search is broken, switch to Google

Tags: feature-request, search, google

> **Related:**
>   [Can we have a setting that defaults our searches to Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/can-we-have-a-setting-that-defaults-our-searches-to-google)

Every time I try to find something in SO, it is a waste of time, the results does not have relevance and often the question I'm looking for does not even show up in the results.

I immediately switch to Google and the top result is often what I was looking for (or in the top 5 results)

Stop fighting with search, embrace the leader.

Options:

- Allow a preference that always use Google
- Two panes search, one with SO internal search and the other with Google Search
- Phase out internal search and use it only for Related Questions (that will free some resources involved with search)

**Note:** I know I can always use Google with site:SO, but I think the problem is for all the users.

Comment: I like the internal search much more than Google. I can always find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've always found everything I needed with internal search, and I've never had to resort to google.

Comment: google and our internal search are good at different things (now that I've improved our internal search and added advanced search clauses). I don't view one as a *replacement* for the other; they complement each other.

Comment: Jeff: I agree, that is why I propose a dual pane search

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, Google cannot offer StackOverflow-specific search features such as tag-specific searches:

- **[tag] apples oranges**
- **[tag] [another-tag] apples oranges**

... and other *Advanced Super Ninja Search options*:

- **posts from a specific user**
  [image] `user:1234 apples oranges`
- **posts with a minimum number of votes**
  [image] `votes:15 apples oranges`
- **questions with a minimum number of views**
  [image] `views:250 apples oranges`
- **questions with an accepted answer**
  [image] `hasaccepted:1 apples oranges`
- **accepted answers**
  [image] `isaccepted:1 apples oranges`
- **questions with a minimum number of answers**
  [image] `answers:1 apples oranges`
- **closed questions**
  [image] `closed:1 apples oranges`
- **community wiki posts**
  [image] `wiki:1 apples oranges`

Comment: Agreed. I use SO now for some pretty specific searches, but stick with google if I need to just search for possible dupes.

Comment: That's ok, make an Advanced Search for the ninjas, but do not punish everyone else

Comment: How are we punishing you? By making a search that can do stuff Google can't? Oh yeah ... thats real punishment...

Answer (score -4):

Beyond that, I'd expect most users know how to use the Google Site: operator and it's shown on our search page..

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

look there under

### Search Is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!

Comment: But it doesn't work with [this][1] and you have to go to that page, which is really annoying. Maybe a user preference or a dropdown menu in the searchbox would be really better for everyone. 

 [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/search-stackoverflow-and-serverfault-from-firefox-search-box/27818#27818

Comment: just type site:stackoverflow.com in the google search area on your browser, or bookmark the page.

Comment: All of the links in this answer seem to be broken now.