# Search Stack Overflow (and Server Fault) from Firefox search box

Tags: discussion, search, firefox, addon

I don't want to:

- install anything (e.g toolbar)
- type too much

Basically something that would show the SO or SF favicon and do a google site:stackoverflow.com search would be just fine - but I haven't found it

Comment: It may not be enabled by default in later versions of Firefox(?). Enable it by the hamburger menu (upper right) → *More tools* → *Customize toolbar...*  → drag "Search" onto the toolbar. (In any case, the search box is not need. A bookmark with a single letter "keyword" and `%s` substitution sequence works just fine. E.g. "URL" `https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%s` for searching on Stack Overflow with DuckDuckGo. There must be a solid reference somewhere on Super User.)

Comment: Example (but not a canonical): *[Firefox bookmark with wildcard and keyword](https://superuser.com/questions/661116/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mycroft Project](http://mycroft.mozdev.org) to find a search engine for Firefox

Today I was able to [find](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=stackoverflow.com) 2 engines, one written by Alessandro Gentilini and labelled "Stack Overflow" and the other one written by Kalevi Onni and labelled "Stack Overflow (3rd Party - Google)".

I tried the first one and it is working just fine!

There is one for [serverfault.com](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=serverfault.com) and another one for [superuser.com](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=superuser.com)
both written by Soon Van and both functional.

Comment: The ones for serverfault.com and superuser.com do not use google as I was requesting, but the other one does. I'm sure this wasn't there when I wrote the question, but now it is and you win!

Answer (score 10):

I did this back in March of 2009:

```
<searchplugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
 <shortname>Stack Overflow</shortname>
 <description>Stack Overflow Google Search</description>
 <inputencoding>UTF-8</inputencoding>
 <img height="16" width="16" />data:image/x-icon;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAGZmZu6+gNhWI+aeQfvv35lmM8+4oOB4T/fd0+CGEbuZd9bCrf///+HClvPPoOSWMbSPaeWObOiae9thMvro4vffwOTWyequYPj18f337/XXsOimUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAHAP8ALAAAAAAQABAAAAVhICOOYjYJCKmSkjBRaxwJRxZXzpgdQhRviYdGRDlJVoRLIjgsTmyrTOARrCBSJMPCgmEQNINNrEAmKwyNSsyggJTJKgBAhbEsDAy5SC/v9/NzgIB+fIF6MXuGhIuHjIwMIQA7</img>
 <url template="http://www.google.com/search" method="GET" type="text/html">
     <param value="site:stackoverflow.com {searchTerms}" name="q" />
     <param value="utf-8" name="ie" />
     <param value="utf-8" name="oe" />
     <param value="t"name="aq" />
 </url>
 <searchform>http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com</searchform>
</searchplugin>
```

[image]

Comment: This needs more upvote love. It is the right answer; and easily modifiable to any of the Trilogy, Meta and/or the StackExchange sites!

Comment: I would upvote immediately and delete my own answer in favor to this one. But I can't get it running. Well, it's a complicated task anyway: Create file, copy, past, save. Feeling like an idiot...

Comment: +1 It works! Seems to have been an issue with a missing blank between the attributes in the 4th `Param` node. I'm going to delete my answer because this is, what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @The Chairman I think I may be the idiot, seeing as how I managed to mangle my own XML while copying it into my blog ;) fixed the space in the snippet - cheers!

Comment: is your site currently down?

Comment: @RexM The link is broken now. Where I can find your search provider?

Comment: @AlexandrAbakumov I put the snippet in the post. I am not sure if this even works anymore - it's 5 years old.

Answer (score 10):

This already exists and is served up by every site in the trilogy.

View source and look for

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
      title="Meta Stack Overflow" href="http://sstatic.net/mso/opensearch.xml">
```

Just use the little drop-down menu in the search bar next to the address bar on most browsers.

[image]

(It is a bit different in Google Chrome as Chrome has only one unified address bar, as Semi points out in his answer)

Alternately going to

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Look for "search {site} with.." where you can type and press enter to use an alternative search engine:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add that for any Google Chrome users reading this, just do this:

1. Search for anything in the stackoverflow search. Chrome will automatically learn that it is a search.
2. In the address bar, start typing "stackoverflow" until it completes to "stackoverflow.com/",  Hit tab, and now the address bar should say "Search stackoverflow.com:" in light blue.  Now just type your search terms after that and hit enter.

Comment: Thanks! I would up-vote this but I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, right-click on the search box and select 'Add a **K** eyword for this Search...'.

Then in your address bar you can go something like:

```
o <search string here>
```

Presuming you set the keyword to <kbd>o</kbd> for SO, of course :)

I do this with several custom search fields inside Firefox.

Comment: About same operation for Opera, right-click, "Create Search...", and here I have so, su, sf as search keywords ;)

Comment: In firefox 3.0.15 (linux) there isn't any `Add a _K_eyword for this Search...` either in the right-click or left-click menu

Comment: I did this on Windows with FF 3.5

Comment: and the 'K' should be underlined there

Comment: In Firefox 10,11 (perhaps few versions earlier) you need to right-click in the search text box **on the stackoverflow page** and select "Add Keyword to this Search..."

Answer (score 0):

[This functionality was added in Firefox 83](https://superuser.com/a/1604926/537480)

[Firefox support: Add search engines](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox#w_add-search-engines), then you can tab-search like on Chrome.