# Firefox Google search to use only stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, search, google, firefox

There are Firefox plugins out there that do search on stackoverflow using stackoverflow.com search engine. What I would be interested in is searching from Firefox search box using Google for only stackoverflow.com content.

The way I see it, this would still use Google as search engine, but would add site:stackoverflow.com automatically to every query.

Maybe this can be done by adding a new search engine to Firefox that uses original Google engine as default?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/search-stackoverflow-and-serverfault-from-firefox-search-box (with many good answers)

Comment: You are right. Now I'm ashamed :/ :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a search shortcut for:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+myquestion
```

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark a Google search where you have used `site:stackoverflow.com`, 
e.g. `CPU site:stackoverflow.com`.

Then edit the bookmark (menu Bookmarks/Organize Bookmarks.../Bookmarks Menu/<select the bookmark - it is at the end>):

- Fill out the `keyword` field. E.g. with "so".
- Replace the word you used in the original search (CPU in the example above) with `%s`.

Now searches in Stack Overflow can be done directly from the address bar, e.g.:

```
so wix installer
```

(<kbd>F6</kbd> toggles focus to the address bar.)