# Search all Stack Exchange Sites from Google

Tags: feature-request, search, subdomains

Is there a simple way to search all Stack Exchange sites (i.e. including those with their own domain; e.g. Stack Overflow) using Google's `site:` option?

I.e., for lots of questions I want to search `serverfault.com`, `stackexchange.com` and `dba.stackexchange.com` from within Google.

I suspect not as if there were any common route domain I'd guess it would be `stackexchange.com`.  However, if there isn't, would it be feasible to suggest an enhancement where `stackoverflow.com` (and any other sites on their own domains) can also be shown on a subdomain of `stackexchange.com` to enable this?

**Related questions**

- This gives information on searching Stack Overflow only; not all sites. *[Fast way to search stackoverflow.com using google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49313/fast-way-to-search-stackoverflow-com-using-google)*
- This question is regarding browser add-ons, rather than standard search engine functionality: *[search stackoverflow (and serverfault) from firefox search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/search-stackoverflow-and-serverfault-from-firefox-search-box)*
- This question doesn't specify search method / the answers don't list an option for searching all sites via a search engine: *[Is there a way to search all sites at once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70331/is-there-a-way-to-search-all-sites-at-once)*

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/search does that, as was mentioned in the third of the questions you mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on technicalities, you could say yes or no.

@Alex mentioned the Stack Exchange [search page](https://stackexchange.com/search), which you could argue either way since:

- It's using a search engine (Google), just a custom search though
- But you're not actually in Google

This is the best way out of all the options. Of course speaking of your feature request, I can't remember which post but a community manager mentioned that the original three and certain others with their own exceptions (i.e [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions)) will not have the `.stackexchange` within the URL to prevent confusion as some might not realize that Stack Overflow has expanded into Stack Exchange.

This of course, does break the usage of [`site:stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange&oq=site%3Astackexchange&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5622j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackexchange.com+) which searches through all sites containing `stackexchange.com`. Unfortunately, if you use this method, you really can't search with the rest of the sites without the domain.

You can use search operators (credits to @Dan Bron). To search them all for example:

```
search_term site:stackexchange.com | site:stackoverflow.com | site:serverfault.com | site:stackapps.com | site:superuser.com | site:mathoverflow.net
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, http://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com URL does work. But this doesn't mean Google includes it with `site:stackexchange.com`  as the URL is a redirect, the resource still lives under `mathoverflow.net`

Comment: You can search all the domains simultaneously using the standard search operators, e.g. `[atwood \(site:stackoverflow.com | site:superuser.com | site:mathoverflow.net | site:stackexchange.com\)](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicorns+site%3Astackexchange.com+%7C+site%3Astackoverflow.com+%7C+site%3Asuperuser.com+%7C+site%3Amathoverflow.com) .