# Add "Search Other Sites" to Search Results Page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

<sup>*Note: I am re-thinking and simplifying this feature request from a previous post (now deleted).*</sup>

When you search Stack Overflow...

[image]

...it would be nice if the search results included a quick way to re-submit the search to Google, Bing, or wherever.

[image]

Copy the text of the original search into the "other search" boxes for a quick way to search Stack Overflow using other search engines.

This would alleviate some of the [criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6776) that sometimes [Google searches work better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13117/search-is-broken-switch-to-google-closed) while adding a nice way to search Stack Overflow using other search engines.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites

Comment: I thought that user was asking a way to search other Stack sites.

Comment: Related, not a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this completed since that functionality is available on the search page itself:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search/