# Since the SO search is not that good, please have a link to google search or provide some kind of similar option

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a setting that defaults our searches to Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/can-we-have-a-setting-that-defaults-our-searches-to-google)

Rather than doing a search from google or needing a google toolbar, might SO be able to put the google search entry on the page, or use google for searching?  Right now the search on SO is pretty bad.

Comment: The search is fine. In fact, here's your dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/bing-bong-bing-bong

Comment: the search is not fine.  In fact it is brain damaged.  It is so bad that the "normal" search edit box should be removed and replaced with the other two in place of it.  I should not have to go to a "search" page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that this is a dupe, your feature request is already implemented. Scroll to the bottom of the [Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and you'll see search boxes for Google and Bing.

Comment: That's nice, but why wouldn't those be in place of the search edit box on the normal SO pages?  Why do I have to go to a "search" page?

Comment: No, they should not. They do not provide the SO-specific features that **are** useful. So unless we're going to have **three** search boxes on every single page of the site, the current implementation is correct.